# Cannot access the Custom UILabel in a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

this is Nsr (just a beginner in xcoding), using xcode 4.3.3,

I've made a Custom UITableview with Custom UITableviewcell through storyboarding,
I have a UIBUtton and a UILabel in my custom cell.
i'v remove the cell selection (also cleared the background) so that only the buttons can be accessable which works as a backgound for the custom UILabel.

Now there are bunch of buttons since of using data array, and when i click any button, it segues to the other view (detail view), all i wanted is to set the custom Label (set over the detail view) from the previous selected button with "Label"...
means new Label = previous page's clicked Label from the custom tableview..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Custom *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[Custom alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.myLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.myTable reloadData];

}
```

I hope you get my problem, very sorry for my poor english..
Please help me, im in a real mess, coz this problem already took my 3 days :(
Thanx in advance, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

function return Custom cell but in header you write UItableviewCell change this to Custom